# How to convert a unicode list of dictionary to list of dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, unicode

I have a list of dictionaries which comes as a unicode and the dictionary comes out as a string. I want to remove the unicode bit from the list and convert string dictionaries to normal dicts, to make it a complete list of dicts.

This is how it looks as of now :

> u'["{"status": "fulfillable", "externalServiceRequestId":
>   "15_jan_003", "updatedOn": "2018-01-15T07:12:23.412", "createdOn":
>   "2018-01-15T07:12:22.826", "expectations": {"containers": []},
>   "serviceRequests": [{"status": "fulfillable",
>   "externalServiceRequestId": "15_jan_00_01", "updatedOn":
>   "2018-01-15T07:12:23.412", "createdOn": "2018-01-15T07:12:22.826",
>   "expectations": {"containers": [{"products": [{"productQuantity": 20,
>   "productAttributes": {"filter_parameters": ["product_sku =
>   \'41_test\'"]}}]}]}, "actuals": {"containers": []}, "type":
>   "PICK_LINE"}, {"status": "fulfillable", "externalServiceRequestId":
>   "11_jan_025", "updatedOn": "2018-01-15T07:12:23.412", "createdOn":
>   "2018-01-15T07:12:22.827", "expectations": {"containers":
>   [{"products": [{"productQuantity": 20, "productAttributes":
>   {"filter_parameters": ["product_sku = \'5003\'"]}}]}]}, "actuals":
>   {"containers": []}, "type": "PICK_LINE"}], "actuals": {"containers":
>   []}, "attributes": {"pps_bin_id": null, "complete_time":
>   "2018-01-15T07:16:21.996532+00:00", "priority": 1, "pps_id": null,
>   "pps_seat_name": null, "order_options": {"pick_after_time":
>   "2017-10-01 09:15:00", "pick_before_time": "2018-11-04 09:20:00"},
>   "user_name": null}, "type": "PICK"}", "{"status": "complete",
>   "externalServiceRequestId": "15_jan_003", "updatedOn":
>   "2018-01-15T07:12:58.395", "createdOn": "2018-01-15T07:12:22.826",
>   "expectations": {"containers": []}, "serviceRequests": [{"status":
>   "complete", "externalServiceRequestId": "15_jan_00_01", "updatedOn":
>   "2018-01-15T07:12:58.443", "createdOn": "2018-01-15T07:12:22.826",
>   "expectations": {"containers": [{"products": [{"productQuantity": 20,
>   "productAttributes": {"filter_parameters": ["product_sku =
>   \'41_test\'"]}}]}]}, "actuals": {"containers": [{"products":
>   [{"productQuantity": 20, "productAttributes": {"pdfa_values":
>   {"product_sku": "41_test"}}}], "state": "complete", "barcode": null,
>   "type": "VIRTUAL"}]}, "type": "PICK_LINE"}, {"status": "complete",
>   "externalServiceRequestId": "11_jan_025", "updatedOn":
>   "2018-01-15T07:12:58.542", "createdOn": "2018-01-15T07:12:22.827",
>   "expectations": {"containers": [{"products": [{"productQuantity": 20,
>   "productAttributes": {"filter_parameters": ["product_sku =
>   \'5003\'"]}}]}]}, "actuals": {"containers": [{"products": [], "state":
>   "complete", "barcode": null, "type": "VIRTUAL"}]}, "type":
>   "PICK_LINE"}], "actuals": {"containers": []}, "attributes":
>   {"pps_bin_id": "7", "complete_time":
>   "2018-01-15T07:16:57.003651+00:00", "priority": 1, "pps_id": "1",
>   "pps_seat_name": "front_1", "order_options": {"pick_after_time":
>   "2017-10-01 09:15:00", "pick_before_time": "2018-11-04 09:20:00"},
>   "user_name": "admin"}, "type": "PICK"}"]'

I tried to use encode() method which removes the u bit from the list but still leaves it as a string. Also the dicts inside the list are string, which needs to be as dicts only.

If I use ast.literal_eval(), it gives an error - seems it's not able to evaluate.

> In [60]: new = ast.literal_eval(data)   File "", line 1
>       ["{"status": "fulfillable", "externalServiceRequestId": "15_jan_003", "updatedOn": "2018-01-15T07:12:23.412", "createdOn":
>   "2018-01-15T07:12:22.826", "expectations": {"containers": []},
>   "serviceRequests": [{"status": "fulfillable",
>   "externalServiceRequestId": "15_jan_00_01", "updatedOn":
>   "2018-01-15T07:12:23.412", "createdOn": "2018-01-15T07:12:22.826",
>   "expectations": {"containers": [{"products": [{"productQuantity": 20,
>   "productAttributes": {"filter_parameters": ["product_sku =
>   '41_test'"]}}]}]}, "actuals": {"containers": []}, "type":
>   "PICK_LINE"}, {"status": "fulfillable", "externalServiceRequestId":
>   "11_jan_025", "updatedOn": "2018-01-15T07:12:23.412", "createdOn":
>   "2018-01-15T07:12:22.827", "expectations": {"containers":
>   [{"products": [{"productQuantity": 20, "productAttributes":
>   {"filter_parameters": ["product_sku = '5003'"]}}]}]}, "actuals":
>   {"containers": []}, "type": "PICK_LINE"}], "actuals": {"containers":
>   []}, "attributes": {"pps_bin_id": null, "complete_time":
>   "2018-01-15T07:16:21.996532+00:00", "priority": 1, "pps_id": null,
>   "pps_seat_name": null, "order_options": {"pick_after_time":
>   "2017-10-01 09:15:00", "pick_before_time": "2018-11-04 09:20:00"},
>   "user_name": null}, "type": "PICK"}", "{"status": "complete",
>   "externalServiceRequestId": "15_jan_003", "updatedOn":
>   "2018-01-15T07:12:58.395", "createdOn": "2018-01-15T07:12:22.826",
>   "expectations": {"containers": []}, "serviceRequests": [{"status":
>   "complete", "externalServiceRequestId": "15_jan_00_01", "updatedOn":
>   "2018-01-15T07:12:58.443", "createdOn": "2018-01-15T07:12:22.826",
>   "expectations": {"containers": [{"products": [{"productQuantity": 20,
>   "productAttributes": {"filter_parameters": ["product_sku =
>   '41_test'"]}}]}]}, "actuals": {"containers": [{"products":
>   [{"productQuantity": 20, "productAttributes": {"pdfa_values":
>   {"product_sku": "41_test"}}}], "state": "complete", "barcode": null,
>   "type": "VIRTUAL"}]}, "type": "PICK_LINE"}, {"status": "complete",
>   "externalServiceRequestId": "11_jan_025", "updatedOn":
>   "2018-01-15T07:12:58.542", "createdOn": "2018-01-15T07:12:22.827",
>   "expectations": {"containers": [{"products": [{"productQuantity": 20,
>   "productAttributes": {"filter_parameters": ["product_sku =
>   '5003'"]}}]}]}, "actuals": {"containers": [{"products": [], "state":
>   "complete", "barcode": null, "type": "VIRTUAL"}]}, "type":
>   "PICK_LINE"}], "actuals": {"containers": []}, "attributes":
>   {"pps_bin_id": "7", "complete_time":
>   "2018-01-15T07:16:57.003651+00:00", "priority": 1, "pps_id": "1",
>   "pps_seat_name": "front_1", "order_options": {"pick_after_time":
>   "2017-10-01 09:15:00", "pick_before_time": "2018-11-04 09:20:00"},
>   "user_name": "admin"}, "type": "PICK"}"]
>                ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: That's a JSON string. Just use a JSON parser?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string representation of list to list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list-in-python)

Comment: @advay.umare ast.literal_eval() is unable to evaluate this, even after it's decoded.

Comment: `my_Dict=json.loads(my_string_text)`

Comment: @Ayush then you might use json. As shown in another answer there by Ryan.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought to do but it did not help.

    384             raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")

ValueError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 5 (char 4)

Comment: You have two problems; you need to unwrap the Python `repr()` around the entire string, and then decode the embedded JSON. Neither of these is an uncommon or hard problem, though a single duplicate won't solve all of it. Still, voting to close.

Comment: @Ayush I think the encodings not right. How is this string getting generated?

Comment: It's response from django view HttpResponse, I'm using request.get to make the call.

Comment: then add headers in request for json response..

Answer (score 0):

dump your unicode list of dicts and then load using json.

```
x = u'["{"status": "fulfillable", "externalServiceRequestId": "15_jan_003", "updatedOn": "2018-01-15T07:12:23.412", "createdOn": "2018-01-15T07:12:22.826", "expectations": {"containers": []}, "serviceRequests": [{"status": "fulfillable", "externalServiceRequestId": "15_jan_00_01", "updatedOn": "2018-01-15T07:12:23.412", "createdOn": "2018-01-15T07:12:22.826", "expectations": {"containers": [{"products": [{"productQuantity": 20, "productAttributes": {"filter_parameters": ["product_sku = \'41_test\'"]}}]}]}, "actuals": {"containers": []}, "type": "PICK_LINE"}, {"status": "fulfillable", "externalServiceRequestId": "11_jan_025", "updatedOn": "2018-01-15T07:12:23.412", "createdOn": "2018-01-15T07:12:22.827", "expectations": {"containers": [{"products": [{"productQuantity": 20, "productAttributes": {"filter_parameters": ["product_sku = \'5003\'"]}}]}]}, "actuals": {"containers": []}, "type": "PICK_LINE"}], "actuals": {"containers": []}, "attributes": {"pps_bin_id": null, "complete_time": "2018-01-15T07:16:21.996532+00:00", "priority": 1, "pps_id": null, "pps_seat_name": null, "order_options": {"pick_after_time": "2017-10-01 09:15:00", "pick_before_time": "2018-11-04 09:20:00"}, "user_name": null}, "type": "PICK"}", "{"status": "complete", "externalServiceRequestId": "15_jan_003", "updatedOn": "2018-01-15T07:12:58.395", "createdOn": "2018-01-15T07:12:22.826", "expectations": {"containers": []}, "serviceRequests": [{"status": "complete", "externalServiceRequestId": "15_jan_00_01", "updatedOn": "2018-01-15T07:12:58.443", "createdOn": "2018-01-15T07:12:22.826", "expectations": {"containers": [{"products": [{"productQuantity": 20, "productAttributes": {"filter_parameters": ["product_sku = \'41_test\'"]}}]}]}, "actuals": {"containers": [{"products": [{"productQuantity": 20, "productAttributes": {"pdfa_values": {"product_sku": "41_test"}}}], "state": "complete", "barcode": null, "type": "VIRTUAL"}]}, "type": "PICK_LINE"}, {"status": "complete", "externalServiceRequestId": "11_jan_025", "updatedOn": "2018-01-15T07:12:58.542", "createdOn": "2018-01-15T07:12:22.827", "expectations": {"containers": [{"products": [{"productQuantity": 20, "productAttributes": {"filter_parameters": ["product_sku = \'5003\'"]}}]}]}, "actuals": {"containers": [{"products": [], "state": "complete", "barcode": null, "type": "VIRTUAL"}]}, "type": "PICK_LINE"}], "actuals": {"containers": []}, "attributes": {"pps_bin_id": "7", "complete_time": "2018-01-15T07:16:57.003651+00:00", "priority": 1, "pps_id": "1", "pps_seat_name": "front_1", "order_options": {"pick_after_time": "2017-10-01 09:15:00", "pick_before_time": "2018-11-04 09:20:00"}, "user_name": "admin"}, "type": "PICK"}"]'

y = json.dumps(x)
z = json.loads(y) ## will give normal string notation of you thing
```

now you can convert your strings dicts to normal dicts using this.

```
op = [ast.literal_eval(a) for a in z]
```

Comment: It gives exactly the same as it was.

Comment: your question says `" I want to remove the unicode bit from the list"`

Comment: wih the output of json.loads(y), you use eval. Updated my answer

Comment: questions say - Also the dicts inside the list are string, which needs to be as dicts only.

Comment: Following your answer, I'm getting error - SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing, at the last line. As I have written eval fails to do what it should do.

Comment: looks like your list has litsts and normal dicts as well.